# siunitx with product-units, mixed units

Tags: siunitx

Is the following possible with full [`siunitx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) syntax?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

$\SI{80}{\micro\meter}\times\SI{1.25}{mm}$

\end{document}
```

For clarification:

I guess there's a difference between the two following statements (maybe not?):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

$\SI{80}{\um}\times\SI{1.25}{\um}$
$\SI{80x1.25}{\um}$

\end{document}
```

What would be the equivalent for the statement above (with different units)?

Comment: What do you mean by "full" syntax?  And why `mm` and not `\milli\meter` in the second unit?

Comment: Basically replacing the "\times" by some siunitx code. "mm" because it's shorter and I can't see a difference in the document (not relevant for question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would do it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\noindent You can write ``\verb|\SI{80}{\um} \times \SI{1.25}{\mm}|'' and get the output
\begin{equation}
  \SI{80}{\um} \times \SI{1.25}{\mm}
\end{equation}
but it is not possible to write it with ``full \verb|siunitx| syntax'', as thew OP calls it. The reason for this is given by the author of the package, Joseph  Wright, in a comment to this post.

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks for showing the shortened versions for the units. Updated the question. Not related: Is there an automated way of including the rendered output into the post?

Comment: @StefanKuczera No, and unlikely to be. Interface very hard to imagine, use case unclear, _etc._

Comment: @JosephWright I assume that your answer is referring to my unrelated question in the comment above. As for my original question, Svend's answer is as good as it gets I guess.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg, I do not iunderstand the frase `it is not possible to write \SI{80 x 1.25}{\um}`, that seems to compile just fine and gives the same result as in (1)

Comment: @daleif True! I forgot to get different units. I'll change my answer now. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: ahh, now I get it, hadn't noticed the different units.